# How to fix "Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code."

Tags: contract-development

How do I determine what functions aren't implementing? I will paste the code from both the token and crowdsale contract if needed (which I suspect it will be).

Answer (score 1):

Go through the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/) to understand the syntax and how to import other files and libraries in your contract.

Answer (score 0):

A token does not necessarily require a name or a symbol. Those are only for visualization purposes - to be displayed for example in Etherscan when displaying token details.

However, if you wish to add those details to your token you can inherit from OpenZeppelin's `DetailedERC20` which adds those details.

The total supply of a token is saved in the `BasicToken` contract. You should inherit from that contract and add the required total supply in a constructor. Something like this:

```
contract OwnToken is DetailedERC20, BasicToken 
{
    constructor(uint256 initialAmount, string _name, uint8 _decimals, string _symbol) 
    DetailedERC20(_name, _symbol, _decimals)
    public
    {
        totalSupply_ = initialAmount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lauri, thank you for the info. I now need to know which contracts to use in remix to get a final result of a token contract and a crowdsale contract that work together. I also need to know where I add the name, symbol and total supply. Also, I read somewhere that I should add a 'using' statement but again, which contrtact to put that in. And finally, do I change the basictoken.sol to the name of my token or does that matter? Many thanks again!

Comment: Hi Lauri, I have been working on this and I have one question...where do I add the above constructor? ie. which file and where in the file or do I substitute the above for an existing constructor and if so, in which file? Thanks again.

Comment: Create a new file for your own token - in my example it's called `OwnToken`. That way you can easily add functionality to it without modifying the original OpenZeppelin "templates".

Comment: In MEW and get the following msg:  "throw" is deprecated in favour of "revert()", "require()" and "assert()".
        if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { throw; }
                                                                                                                                            ^---^,      for this line: if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { throw; } I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use zeppelinOS or remix, although I know how to use remix, I couldn't get it to work because I got an error saying contract can't implement all functions. Also, I ran the contracts through Securify but every contract I ran it gave me lots of errors.